# Force ALL Android links to open in disambiguation dialog. Even when app has intent filter

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-12

I have a common usage case in android where sometimes I want to open a youtube link from another app (reddit, facebook, etc) sometimes in the app, and sometimes in the browser. I sometimes want the browser (firefox) so I can "queue" it up to watch later or sent it to my desktop. This also happens with the github app when I want to open a repo/issue in browser vs the app.

I use the "Better open with" app to intercept link open requests and direct them to my browser/app of choice, but it does not work with certain apps because it is not a  "default supported app" for links that have an app that support intent filters. It just allows the "selection of browsers". this worked ok in android 11, but in android 12 they "simplified" app default links and broke it.

My main issue is that when I turn off an apps default opening for their supported links, they do not show up in the disambiguation list at all anymore. There does not seem to be any option to disable just the intent filter behavior.

I want to short circuit all "intent filter" behavior and always use the disambiguation dialogue to choose whether I want to open a link in the supported app or browser. I NEVER want to go straight to the app.

Does anyone know how to do this? I can jailbreak if that is the only way to do this and a solution exists.

Comment: I'm not using additional app to open links, but have related but different problem. Usually I just choose "Only this time" in disambiguation dialog. But after accidentally choosing "every time", dialog stops appearing. May be do you know a way to reset this setting so disambiguation dialog will show up again?